# How to return a deleted object?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I want test[0] to be untouched, but I want to remove test[1] from the function. This is what came to my mind.

```
var example = function(data){
  this.information = data;

  delete this;
  return this;
}

test[1] = example("hello");
```

Comment: you're passing a string, and _this_ is the global

Comment: That's not how `delete` works.

Comment: What exactly are you after? Can you clarify what the data structure is and what you're trying to accomplish?

Comment: also `delete this` will silently fail even if you use the `new` keyword

Comment: I just want to remove test[1] from existens using a function.

Answer (score 1):

```
Array.splice
```

is your friend.

```
var arr = ["a", "b", "c", "d"];
arr.splice(1, 1);

// Output: ["a", "c", "d"]
```

Further reading: https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/wctc5k7s%28v=vs.94%29.aspx

Comment: why are you using the new keyword for an array?

Comment: Don't you mean:

    arr.splice(2, 3, "21", "31");

Comment: @Josh aah, sorry I miss-read your comment, but that link is a good read anyways, if you haven't already :)